# How to count the most popular value from multiple value pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

i have such a problem:

I have pandas dataframe with shop ID and shop cathegories, looking smth like that:

```
        id          cats
0       10002718    182,45001,83079
1       10004056    9798
2       10009726    17,45528
3       10009752    64324,17
4       1001107     44607,83520,76557
... ... ...
24922   9992184     45716
24923   9997866     77063
24924   9998461     45001,44605,3238,72627,83785
24925   9998954     69908,78574,77890
24926   9999728     45653,44605,83648,85023,84481,68822
```

So the problem is that each shop can have multiple cathegories, and the task is to count frequency of each cathegoty. What's the easiest way to do it?

In conclusion i need to have dataframe with columns

```
        cats        count
0       1           133
1       2           1
2       3           15
3       4           12
```

Comment: you can also lazily get dummies and sum them up: `df['cats'].str.get_dummies(',').sum().reset_index()` if data is not huge.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = (df['cats'].str.split(',')
        .explode()
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('cats')
        .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Or add `expand=True` to `split` to `DataFrame` and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = (df['cats'].str.split(',', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('cats')
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1.head(10))
    cats  count
0     17      2
1  44605      2
2  45001      2
3  83520      1
4  64324      1
5  44607      1
6  45653      1
7  69908      1
8  83785      1
9  83079      1
```